# Problems in transmission and reception in USRP N210

Tags: python-3.x, gnuradio, transmission, usrp

I am developing a code for transmission and reception of a txt file using fec correction and qam modulation. The main problem is in transmission it only send one character or nothing just for a second and then get freeze. It's the first time that i used GNU radio and i don't know what caused this problem can you check the code in the images below and tell me what it could be and how to solve this. If i am doing something wrong please tell me.

Sorry, I don't have the range to post images so instead that I posted links.

This is for TX
[Txcode1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN0u4.png)
[Txcode2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4UtY.png)

This is for RX
[RXcode1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjzwv.png)
[RXcode2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J519q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an outdated version of GNU Radio, and within that, you're using the explicitly deprecated Packet Encoder, which randomly drops data. Don't do that, you had to pick that block from a category called "Deprecated" for a reason.

Also, it looks like you're using Throttle together with hardware. That doesn't work, and GRC also explicitly tells you it's a bad idea – you should pay attention to the console output in the lower left, it contains useful information!

So, don't start a new project on GNU Radio 3.7; GNU Radio 3.8 or 3.9 is trivial to install from Linux distro sources on any modern Linux Distro, and on Windows, you can use the excellent anaconda installer method.

Afterwards, orient on the examples that come with GNU Radio (installed, typically, under /usr/share/gnuradio/examples) in the digital subfolder. `packet_loopback` and other files will be good examples to learn from!

Other than that, make sure you've clicked on the "Get Started" button on gnuradio.org, and followed the tutorials up to the point of the PSK transmission tutorial. This should be a good entry to *exactly* what you're doing.